# ios: UIButton title format delay

Tags: ios, text, formatting, uibutton, delay

I've got some buttons where I left align and line wrap the title text.

When I run the app, there is a delay from where the text is unformatted:

[pre-format text http://imageshack.us/a/img28/1958/preformat.jpg](http://imageshack.us/a/img28/1958/preformat.jpg)

To when the alignment and wrapping take effect:

[post-format text http://imageshack.us/a/img821/6118/postformat.jpg](http://imageshack.us/a/img821/6118/postformat.jpg)

On the simulator the delay is quite noticeable (~ 1 second), on my mate's iPhone 5 the delay is much smaller but still noticeable.

What causes this delay?  Can I get around this delay?

Thanks in advance!

---

**EDIT**
In my viewDidLoad method I create 10 buttons:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= STEP_NUMBER; ++i)
    [self createStepButtion:i isIphone:isIphone isRetina:isRetina];
```

In createStepButton, the relevant code is below:

```
UIButton * b = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

// Listener
[b addTarget:self action:@selector(goToStep:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[self.scrollView addSubview:b];

// Set button size.
CGFloat width = self.scrollView.frame.size.width;
// CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)
int y = stepNum * margin + (stepNum - 1) * buttonHeight;
int buttonWidth = width - margin * 2;
b.frame = CGRectMake(margin, y, buttonWidth, buttonHeight);

b.layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius;
b.clipsToBounds = YES;
b.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = YES;

// Image
[b setImage:img forState:UIControlStateNormal];
b.imageEdgeInsets = [self makeImageInsets:buttonWidth];

// Text
[b setTitleEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, titleLeftMargin, 0, titleRightMargin)];
b.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft;
b.titleLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
[b setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i - %s", stepNum, STEP_NAMES[stepNum - 1]]forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[b setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
b.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:fontSize];

// Background
[b setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

// The step number this button represents.
b.tag = stepNum;
```

Comment: Show some code, please. Need more details about how you are setting up the buttons.

Comment: It depends on where you are setting this formatting part. Move it to viewDidLoad/viewWillAppear.

Comment: @KurtRevis added the code to the question.

Comment: @ACB, the formatting code is in a method (createStepButton) that's called from viewDidLoad.